# Does XMLHttpRequest updates data 'AUTOMATICALLY'?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a question about, the great function of javascript i.e., 
**XMLHttpRequest()**

Does this function auto updates any document?**If its content changes?**

Or I have to do it using **setInterval()** ?

Actually, I am creating a chat system, in which file containing messages has to be refreshed. The messages file is loaded into main page using **XMLHttpRequest()**.

So, I want to know can **XMLHttpRequest()** auto refresh or not.

I have also another question.....

In the usage of **XMLHttpRequest()**, the format is:

```
my.open( METHOD, URL, BOOLEAN );
```

IN THE BOOLEAN WE ALWAYS PUT FALSE. WHY?

WHAT IF I USE TRUE?

Comment: You'll need to create a new request each time. Using setInterval() sounds fine. You could look into web sockets which would keep the connection open for live updates.

Comment: The boolean is false to indicate a synchronous download, true would enable asynchronous behaviour (i.e. non-blocking).

Answer (score 0):

It's not updating automatically. You have to do the `my.open(..)` again.

The third parameter is for the `async` mode.

If you set it to `false` the client waits til it finished his action, before doing something else.

If set to `true` the client can perform other actions, while doing the action.

This is the main purpose for AJAX being `(A)synchronous (J)avaScript (a)nd (X)ML`